# Bernoulli scheme, probability of failure

Tags: probability

In Bernoulli scheme the probability of success is  *p* and the probability of failure is *1-p*.

What is the probability that the failure comes twice in a row sooner than the failure-success?

Comment: I think, you can look at it as the probability of having two failures in a row till the first success. Then it will be $Geom(q^2)$

Comment: It looks simple, but I can't do it. Can you solve this problem? please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question:

I think it's following the first failed attempt to (number of previous success doesn't matter). So

P(f|f) = 1 - p

P(s|f) = p